# Bootstrap progress bar starting from center and expanding to the left or right

Tags: bootstrap-4

I want to have a bootstrap progress bar which starts from the center of itself and is then able to expand to the left and to the right, depending on the values.

Here is an image created with Indesign from what I want to achieve:

[image: Bootstrap progress bar two ways]

The 0 at the left side of the progress bar is the minimum value, in the middle of it (10) is the starting value and at the right side is the maximum value (20). The 7 is the actual value. Based on the actual value the progress bar should expand either to the left or to the right, depending wether it is bigger or smaller than the starting value.

I know how progress bars work in general in bootstrap but I have no solution for my specific problem.

I'm using Bootstrap v4.1.2.